# Does Yahoo finance adjust ETF's historical data for splits and dividends? (not stocks or shares)

Tags: etf, stock-analysis, stock-valuation, yahoo-finance, chart

On the ETF's graphs I see there are steep falls. There is a legend indicating the ETF was split 1:10. However like Stocks or Shares, I don't see the price being adjusted for splits.
Is this correct, is there a way to see ETF data adjusted for Splits.

For Example See LABD:
LABD on 03/28/2018 shows split of 1 for 10  and on 03/29/2018 again 1 for 10.
See [graph](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/LABD#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%3D%3D) on 3/28/18

Comment: Yahoo is notorious for bad data.  Other sites that offer charts have the data correctly adjusted so the charts are good.  I don't remember which one (perhaps Barcharts or StockCharts) but with a click you can see an adjusted chart or an unadjusted chart.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer here is that Yahoo's data suppliers have got it wrong.  It appears to have adjusted it twice and it's disturbing that such an obvious error still remains in there after almost 4 months.

Yahoo show the raw data here:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LABD/history?p=LABD

If you select Stock Splits, you'll see two of them consecutively.

Unfortunately there are many data errors in Yahoo Finance (doubled up dividends, dividends missing etc.)

Yahoo appears to source its US data from Commodity Systems Inc (CSI) as shown here:
https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance-for-desktop/SLN2310.html?impressions=true
So this error is likely to have originated from CSI.